# How to fix 'Value name of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject'

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I'm am using Volley to send an HTTP request in Android and I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

On the server side, I use a PHP script to get values from the database.

My Android code:

```
String server_url = "http://192.168.225.40/server/greetings.php";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            name.setText(response.getString("name"));
                            email.setText(response.getString("email"));
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(firebaseUser!=null){
                    if(!firebaseUser.getEmail().isEmpty())
                    {
                        email.setText(firebaseUser.getEmail());}

                }

                error.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        );
        singletonclasshttp.getInstance(getActivity()).addtorequestque(jsonObjectRequest);
```

My PHP script:

```
?php
$username="root";
$password="";
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "test";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
$sql = "select * from user where uid =1;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data=array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
    echo json_encode(array("name"=>$row["name"],"email"=>$row["email"],"type"=>$row["type"]));


}


?>
```

I need to parse the JSON and set the value for the text fields.

Comment: post your   reponse class and gson response

Answer (score 1):

use [this](http://jsonschema2pojo.org) site to generate a correct response class from json response

Comment: Thanks for the response. the error was due to a typos in my code.

Comment: glade to hear that. feel free to up vote and accept my answer thx.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting JsonArray. You should use `StringRequest`. Then convert String to JsonArray and get JsonObject from the array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. the error was due to a typos in my code.